# How to deploy a Rails application with an internally signed SSL certificate (SSL_CERT_FILE and openssl related)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a few questions regarding deploying a Rails application with an SSL certificate.

Background:

- Rails 3.2.16 / Ruby 1.9.3
- SAN SSL certificate signed by internal Windows CA server
- App deployed to Ubuntu 12.04 servers with Apache/Passenger

As per, https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550, Windows clients using Ruby `net/http` do not trust the certificate on the Ubuntu severs. I assume this is becuase the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable is not set (despite the fact the internal root certificates are installed on the Ubuntu servers and deployed to Windows clients by Group Policy..?)

I want to be able to run the following code snippet from any client of my app (Windows or Ubuntu)

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse('https://ubuntu-server.internal.com/')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.start { |agent| agent.get(uri.path) }
```

1. Should i bundle the internal CA root certificate (and intermediate certificate, and the rest of the CURL cert bundle) with the app and then set `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']` in code?)
2. Should i include only the internal CA root certificate in the app and use an initializer to setup net/http before use? This seems to be the approach of the RubyInstaller https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/rake/contrib/uri_ext.rb#L287-295 but i don't really know how i would go about coding this?
3. Something else?

Option 2 seems the best to me so far, but as I say i dont know how i would go about setting

```
http.use_ssl = true
http.ca_file = "#{Rails.root}/config/internal-ca.crt"
```

in a Rails initializer.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, with some further Googling i've come up with the following solution:

```
# /config/initializers/ssl.rb

require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
      store.set_default_paths

      store.add_cert(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/ssl/root.crt")))
      store.add_cert(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/ssl/intermediate.crt")))

      self.cert_store = store

      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

Sources

- http://gistflow.com/posts/227-net-http-cheat-sheet
- http://jjinux.blogspot.nl/2012/02/ruby-working-around-ssl-errors-on-os-x.html

This seems to work for me, but i am open to other suggestions.